# Can't open WP7 solution with VS 2010 Express 

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've downloaded a zipped project from https://github.com/slodge/face. This project is a wp7 realization for face.com api. I've just started studying silverlight and wp7 applications, so I'm not strong at it. The problem is that I can't load this solution. The error message is "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the output window for details" 
What do i have to do?[image: this is error]

Comment: Did you check the output window?

Comment: Looks like one of the ".csproj" is not loaded correctly. Are you sure it can be opened with your Express version of VS 2010? Are there "solution folders" (not available in VS 2010 Express)?

Comment: I just downloaded it and it opens fine for me. I think it should be something with your environment.

Comment: D:\education\Third course\semestr 2\Hack day\slodge-face-6b6e529\slodge-face-6b6e529\SmilieHappy\SmilieHappy.csproj : error  : Unable to read the project file 'SmilieHappy.csproj'. 
D:\education\Third course\semestr 2\Hack day\slodge-face-6b6e529\slodge-face-6b6e529\SmilieHappy\SmilieHappy.csproj(147,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone71.Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: There are no "solution folders" in that solution.

Comment: Do you have Windows Phone SDK 7.1 installed on your machine?

Comment: 'WindowsPhone71' was not found. Did you download the last release of SDK? Or may be try to reinstall/repair it.

Comment: Do you have Windows Phone SDK 7.1 installed on your machine?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be opened with vs 2010 express.How can i now it?do i have to install vs 2010 premium?

Comment: I believe solution can be opened with express as well. For this you might need to play a bit with solution file.

Comment: I've installed sdk from this link http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13890, it is Version: 1.0.

Comment: Try to rename `WindowsPhone71` to `WindowsPhone` and see what happens. But I could only be a temporary solution. Or browse to the specified folder and check what's in.

Comment: should i install Windows Phone SDK 7.1?Andriy Buday, how exactly should i play with sln files?

Comment: @Nate - You don't have the latest SDK. The project type guid is for the latest version (7.1). Find the link from Andriy's post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just opened solution and it works ok. I think you have problem with your environment.
From errors you see it appears you have no SDK 7.1

Please [download and install](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570).

Comment: I have 2010 and SDK 7.1 that I actively develop with and I cannot open it.

Comment: Very strange... I also develop for WP7 and I can open.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's my github account... :)

This project is just a 7.1 (Mango) project - so it should load for you.

If it doesn't then please do check the output window for more help.

If it still doesn't then the project itself is quite simple - the main code is in the faceapi class - and should be simple enough to use even without a project file. If you need any more help with it, then email me (see my so profile for email address) or contact me via twitter @slodge

To get the app running you will need your own API key from Face - see https://github.com/slodge/face/blob/master/SmilieHappy/Helpers/FaceApiSecrets.txt

Also, the team at face.com seemed very helpful when I contacted them!

Stuart

Comment: FaceApiSecrets.cs is not checked-in. :) Is it?

Comment: Good point on the secrets - see https://github.com/slodge/face/blob/master/SmilieHappy/Helpers/FaceApiSecrets.txt

Comment: After I Entered my ApiKey and secret,Eventually i could compile and run this app. But when i sent image(the boy with ball) from args.ChosenPhoto, server return me error.

Comment: Here is screenshot of error https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9327eb56604f1f7e&resid=9327EB56604F1F7E!122&parid=9327EB56604F1F7E!104&authkey=!AN5lFJHKWtaboV0

Comment: It's working here for me... In the DoPhotoTask method, change the processed image to the sample - i.e. `var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);` becomes `var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(_sampleBitmap);` - if that works then its something to do with your photo. If that doesn't work then its your api key - try digging into that web exception error to see if face.com is returning you any more info.

Comment: Thank u Stuard!i created new application in api, and it works fine!

Comment: Probably it sounds silly, but i can't add my own pictures to Image folder. When i do it and just replace _sampleBitmap name with it, program thow me "NullReferenceException". How can i fix this problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9332/discussion-between-nate-and-stuart)

Comment: New question. Someone will help you

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered same issue like yours. Some project can open correctly and somes are not. The issue is because the tag  is only support "WindowsPhone" other than "WindowsPhone71".

So the solution is clear, manually edit the ".csproj" file. Change the "WindowsPhone71" to "WindowsPhone".

This issue does because symbols related to the windows phone framework (7.1 or 8.0) are missing. I think why I meet this issue is due because I install SDK7.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 (which sdk not support) through "Web" way.

Here is the link how I install the SDK.
[How to install the Windows Phone Developer Tools on Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx)